# toggle.setchecked inside a onTextChanged event

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use a togglebutton to display the status of a number check when the number is entered in a textbox. I've already set it up with a TextView and that works fine but I'd like to replace it graphically. No errors are thrown up with the following but the state doesn't change with the .SetChanged events in the OnChanged event:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ToggleButton togShortCircuit = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togShortCircuit);
    togShortCircuit.setClickable(false);

    final EditText txtOCVListen = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtOCV);
    txtOCVListen.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            txtOCVListen.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new CustomRangeInputFilter(0f, 16.0f)});

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if(txtOCVListen.getText().toString().equals(null) || txtOCVListen.getText().toString().equals("")){
                fltOCV = 0;
            } else {
                fltOCV = Float.parseFloat(txtOCVListen.getText().toString());
            }

            //Short Circuit
            if (fltOCV < 10.6 && fltULV > 0 && fltULV <= 8.5) {
                TextView lblShortCircuitStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblShortCircuitStatus);
                lblShortCircuitStatus.setText("True");
                lblShortCircuitStatus.setTextColor(0xFFD51817); //Red
                togShortCircuit.setChecked(true);

            } else {
                TextView lblShortCircuitStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblShortCircuitStatus);
                lblShortCircuitStatus.setText("False");
                lblShortCircuitStatus.setTextColor(0xFF808080); //Grey
                togShortCircuit.setChecked(false);
            }
```

Can't seem to figure out how to declare togShortCircuit to have it recognized with the event. Using Android Studio 3.12 and developing for Android 7.0.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the `ToggleButton` state change inside `TextWatcher`, I even try it in my code. Did you debug it and make sure the code run through `togShortCircuit.setChecked(true);` line?

Comment: It looks like it's firing when I do the debug but the state doesn't appear to change. if I put the togShortCircuit.setChecked(true); in the main onCreate body it changes the state just fine so I know it's not the xml. It looks like it's just not passing through to the object.

Also, interesting side note, if I setChecked to true in the main onCreate the setChecked to false in the else part of the statement is firing and the state visibly changes back to false but still won't change back to true within the if statement.